# what is the ability of a programming language to redefine methods for the derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax, overriding, overloading

This is an online C++ test question:

**_** refers to the ability of a programming language to redefine methods for the derived classes ?

A:  Factoring

B:  Inheritance

C:  Overloading

D:  Encapsulation

My idea:

No one is correct.  If C is overriding, it is a correct answer.

Right ?

thanks

Comment: Yeah! Overriding sounds right.  I was thinking overloading as in operator overloading, which replaces the default behaviour of operators for a type.  But then, inheritance fits the supplied sentence.

Comment: Overloading means multiple functions with the same name for different signatures. Overriding would be the correct answer, except it's not in the list, so I'm wondering if they're incorrectly associating it with inheritance.

Comment: I think you are correct, the answer should be overriding, hiding, or polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `C` because the phrase "redefine methods" doesn't suggest "overriding" to me. When you "redefine" something, you are changing it to something different than the original, which is part of what "overloading" is about. A derived class can overload a base class method with a different signature, making it a different method.  Normally that would hide the base class method, but it is possible to skip that, such as with a `using` statement in C++, so the derived class has both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. I would consider it a typo in the test question.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance seems like a good answer to me, although the question seems to assume that you can derive classes.